# Decompressing a MemoryStream using Zlib

Tags: c#, zlib, dotnetzip

I am writing software that deals with a large collection of files that contain zlib compressed data in different sections of the file rather than the entire file itself.  I know how to grab the section(s) I need.  However I was having trouble getting the documented zlib stream classes to work properly.  I googled and tried several different solutions and could not get them to work except one that uses a static method.  The following code works just fine but does not work directly with the Zlib stream class as I would prefer:

```
// reader is the BinaryReader for the original file and... 
// The "Data" section consists of a UInt32 and the compressed data
byte[] compressedStream = reader.ReadBytes((int)Size - 4); // name was kept for code compatibility
MemoryStream deflatedStream = new MemoryStream(ZlibStream.UncompressBuffer(compressedStream), true);
```

I don't really have any issues with using the code above since it gives me the decompressed data I need.  However, I am baffled as to why my original code which instances the zlib stream class directly did not work (since they use the same basic API):

```
MemoryStream compressedStream = new MemoryStream(reader.ReadBytes((int)Size - 4));
ZlibStream deflatedStream = new ZlibStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress, true);
```

Accessing almost any property of "deflatedStream" results in an error.  I assume this means it did not work.  It might be worth noting that I have not yet used the DotNetZip lib and used Zlib.Portable instead (the second most popular library).  However, the API seems to be the same.

Comment: Are you checking `CanRead`, `CanWrite`, `CanSeek`, etc. before using related properties? Please edit your question to a) contain a question and b) present what you're actually having trouble with.

Comment: The docs state that `CanSeek` will always return `false`, so `Position` and `Length` won't work.

Comment: What is the exact error msg?

Comment: "an error", you must post the exception type and error message you get.

Comment: CanRead and CanWrite are both true.  CanSeek is false.  I need to use the Length property and this gives a System.NotSupported exception.  I haven't gotten to the point in the code yet (because of the Length issue) but I also need to be able to wrap the stream in a BinaryReader to get the necessary data out of it.

Comment: If you need to use `Length` then you can't do it with `ZlibStream` (as per [docs](https://documentation.help/DotNetZip/e929017d-485b-f5e8-2083-b99b69ea3688.htm)). Is there any way you can avoid needing `Length`?

Comment: Well I can _assume_ that the length of the uncompressed data stored in the UInt32 before the compressed data is correct.... but there would be no way for me to check for that if I used the ZlibStream.  Since this is my first time doing something like this, I wrote a Debug assertion to make sure unzipping worked properly.  I suppose i confirmed this indirectly but I still need the length data. It seems a bit strange that they wouldn't support that property.  Especially before the stream is potentially changed.  (They could throw the exception if the stream had been modified instead).